# Flow of Azure B2C (OpenID) when using a custom Identity Provider to authenticate and then redirect to external client

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, openid-connect

I'm looking for some advice as I'm getting confused with the flow between my application -> Azure B2C -> Client's application. The ultimate goal is for the user to log into my application, then be automatically authenticated into Azure B2C, and then redirected to the client's application where the final authorization will occur.

Step 1, in order to kick of the flow from my application, I need to make a call to B2C's authorization endpoint, e.g.:

```
https://xxx.b2clogin.com/xxx.onmicrosoft.com/oauth2/v2.0/authorize?p={user_flow}&client_id=xxx&nonce=defaultNonce&redirect_uri={redirect_uri}&scope=openid&response_type=code
```

This in turn calls my custom IdP's authorization endpoint, e.g.:

```
https://example.com/connect/authorize?client_id=7xxx&redirect_uri=https%3a%2f%2fxxx.b2clogin.com%2fxxx.onmicrosoft.com%2foauth2%2fauthresp&response_type=code&scope=openid+profile+email&response_mode=form_post&nonce={nonce}&ui_locales=en-US&state={state}
```

Which contains a RedirectURI value, allowing a redirect back to B2C's /oauth/authresp endpoint.

At this point, I should now be authenticated into B2C. The next part I'm assuming should occur is a redirect to the client's application to allow for the client to call B2C Authorization endpoint to get the logged in user's details.

This is where I think I'm getting confused. B2C is now trying to redirect back to the {redirect_uri} that was passed through during step 1 above. I think typically this would come back to my IdP but in this case I am not interested in additional claims from B2C, I don't need this redirecting back to my custom IdP. Should I be preventing the redirect back to my IdP and instead be redirecting to the client's application so that the client can then call B2Cs authorization endpoint?

I'm afraid I'm understanding this incorrectly from the get-go, so would be extremely grateful for some advice.

Answer (score 0):

The `redirectUri` passed into the first call to `b2clogin.com`, is supposed to be the `uri` for your application, so it can do exactly what you describe - after the user authenticates at your external IdP, the user redirects to B2C, and B2C redirects you to the app (IdP -> B2C -> App).